# Doesn't let me input new data via cin.get after the first one

Tags: c++, arrays, dev-c++

I tried to make a code that takes the first two letters in three separate arrays, and concatenate them. For example, I put Dog, Cat, Rabbit, and it must show "DoCaRa". I tried to use cin.get but it only reads the first one, then it doesn´t let me enter new arrays. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char or1[99],or2[99],or3[99];
 cout << "Enter array: ";
 cin.get (or1, 3);
 cout << "Enter array: ";
 cin.get (or2, 3);
 cout << "Enter array: ";
 cin.get (or3, 3);
 cout << "\n--" << or1 << or2 << or3 << "--\n";
}
```

Output:
Enter array: **dog**
Enter array: Enter array:
--dog--

Comment: Can you clarify your understanding of how this specific `get()` overload work, step by step? In order for the shown code to work each `get()` must obviously read an entire line of text, including the trailing newline, but somehow truncate each line and copy the leading two characters into the array, followed by a `\0`. What, exactly, in your C++ textbook's description of this `get()` overload led you to believe that this is how it works?

Comment: You also need to describe what input you are providing.   Presumably (you haven't mentioned it) you are hitting the <Enter> key after the first two letters.   The first call of `cin.get()` will stop when it encounters the `'\n'` in the stream AND leave that `'\n'` in the stream buffer.   The second call will encounter that `'\n'` and return immediately, and leave that `'\n'` in the stream .....         You could find this by reading the documentation e.g.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: When reading the above documentation link, pay special attention to points 3) and 4)

Comment: The way you are using `cin.get()` will not allow you to reach your goal the way you want.  Don't use `char[]`, use `std::string` instead with `cin >>` or `std::getline()`, and then you can use `std::string::substr()` to extract the first 2 chars of each input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin.get (or1, 3);` reads at most 2 chars until line end but leaves other characters and end-of-line character in the stream, so `cin.get (or1, 3);` reads `do`, `cin.get (or2, 3);` reads `g` until line end, `cin.get (or3, 3);` meets line end and will not give new inputs. Use the entire buffers for reading and `cin.get()` to consume end-of-line character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char or1[99],or2[99],or3[99];
 cout << "Enter array: ";
 cin.get (or1, 99); cin.get(); or1[2] = 0;
 cout << "Enter array: ";
 cin.get (or2, 99); cin.get(); or2[2] = 0;
 cout << "Enter array: ";
 cin.get (or3, 99); cin.get(); or3[2] = 0;
 cout << "\n--" << or1 << or2 << or3 << "--\n";
}
// Output:
// --DoCaRa--
```

Comment: Undefined behavior.